# Missing resource hokuyo_node

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a Hokuyo rangefinder, following the tutorial, but fail at the first step: rosdep install hokuyo_node rviz

It seems that hokuyo_node is not in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:

```
    ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
 Missing resource hokuyo_node ROS path 
    [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros ROS path 
    [1]=/home/dbarry/fuerte_workspace/sandbox ROS path 
    [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks ROS path 
    [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share ROS path 
    [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

But hokuyo_node is in what seems an odd spot:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/

and adding that path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH does not help.

I must be missing something obvious, but need help figuring it out.
Using Ubuntu 12.04, ROS fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48334/missing-resource-hokuyo_node/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hokoyu_node in gazebo_plugins is just an executable.  You are missing the package.  You can install it using

> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers

Or you can install it locally using

> rosco hokuyo_node

This requires the rosinstall bundle:

> sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2012-11-14**:
Excellent answer!  I updated the wiki here:  http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode